# Python, pandas splitting column into two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with multiple columns one of which is a date column. currently the data in that column is in this form: 02/01/2012 9:30

However I would like to split this into two separate columns, date:02/01/2012 and time: 9:30

I have found the following solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.date.str.split(' ',1).tolist(), columns = ['date','time'])
```

However this creates a new dataframe which contains only the two new split columns and not the others as well.

Is there a way to split a column of an existing dataframe without creating a new one?

What is the most computationally efficient way to solve this issue? (the data sets I am working with contain about 20 millions rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[['date','time']] = df.pop('date').str.split(expand=True)
```

Demo

```
In [274]: df
Out[274]:
              date
0  02/01/2012 9:30
1  02/01/2012 9:30
2  02/01/2012 9:30

In [275]: df[['date','time']] = df.pop('date').str.split(expand=True)

In [276]: df
Out[276]:
         date  time
0  02/01/2012  9:30
1  02/01/2012  9:30
2  02/01/2012  9:30
```

Comment: One day... I'll remember to use `pop`

Comment: This worked, but when I ran it my physical memory usage spiked to almost 100% but i guess that just because the data set is huge.

Answer (score 3):

If your `date` column are strings and you just want to split them... then this should work

```
date_time = df.date.str.split(expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'date', 1: 'time'})
df = df.drop('date', 1).join(date_time)
print(df)

   A  B        date  time
0  1  2  02/01/2012  9:30
```

***setup***
*assuming a dataframe `df`*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=['02/01/2012 9:30'], A=[1], B=[2]))

print(df)

   A  B             date
0  1  2  02/01/2012 9:30
```

---

However, assuming your `date` column were in fact datetimes

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.to_datetime(['02/01/2012 9:30']), A=[1], B=[2]))

print(df)

   A  B                date
0  1  2 2012-02-01 09:30:00
```

Then we'd

```
df = df.assign(date=df.date.dt.date, time=df.date.dt.time)

print(df)

   A  B                date
0  1  2 2012-02-01 09:30:00
```